# What beings are above the devas but below Bhagavan?

Tags: gods, philosophy, brahman, shad-darshana

Which beings are more powerful and more exalted than the 33 devas, but not as exalted as Bhagavan? What are the types of beings in this category?

One example of a being in this category would be Adishesha. Who, being timeless, is higher than the devas, but also lower than Bhagavan.

Comment: Provide references to your question, what this based of or is this your thought?

Comment: @Up-In-Air What do you mean?

Comment: @user28653 kindly provide a reference of the scripture from which you have quoted about Adishesha.

Comment: 33 crore is not 33.

Answer (score 1):

In the Vedas, there are individual Divinities called the Devas like Varuna, Ashvins, and more. But there are aggregate conceptual entities like Prajapti, Rudra, Soma, Narayana, Purusha, Manyu, and more. A good analogy is, if Devas are like Nouns then the aggregate entities are like Collective Nouns. So it's very difficult to draw such a line.

Comment: How high are those aggregate entities? Are they eternal, immaterial, and morally perfect, for example?

Comment: @KeoBelur I am not sure what you mean by "High". High vs Low is an adjective. Devas are Cosmic Phenomena. Collective Divinity is the cumulative of many phenomena in one. It seems you are seeking the High God vs Demi-God category of the Abhramic concept.

Comment: @SantatanaDhara When I say that a being is higher, I'm talking about it's degree of glory.

Comment: @KeoBelur if the count of hymns defines the degree of glory then in the Vedas Indra received the highest. Next is Agni. Then Soma. After the Vedic Period Rudra continued to be cumulative of Agni, Soma, Varuna, Maruts, and Vishnu became cumulative of all Adityas. Today major sects revolve around Rudra and Vishnu. Upanishads (the end limbs of Vedas) don't take that approach as they deal with consciousness and reality. In total there are over 14 Vedic Shakas, 6 Darshanas (means to witness), 18 major Puranas, 2 Itihasas, 18 primary Upanishads, 4 sects of Tantra ... and many Devotional hymns. So???

Comment: When I talk about glory, I'm talking about the degree of glory they have objectively, not a  numerical comparison of the number of hymns. Of course, the two correlate, but not perfectly.

Comment: A better way of measuring glory would be their degree of freedom from matter.

Comment: @KeoBelur I can only think of Rudra being that one diety who is addressed by the Vedas as the "Subtle", that "indweller of all Divine". There is "none Second to Rudra", He is the "Vital force", He is "Kaal/Time", he is "tatpurusha = consciousness-unblemished", He is "Intelligence" and "death itself". 
Hope this is what you are looking for?